# Embedding a Leaflet user click Lat, Long into PostGIS SQL?

Tags: postgis, leaflet, sql

I have ran the SQL through a web browser and can connect to the server which returns the result. I just can't get it to work in Leaflet. Any suggestions?

```js
<script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Create Leaflet map object
    var map = L.map('map',{ center: [50.56, -2.44], zoom: 13});

    // // Add OpenStreetMap tile layer to map element
    L.tileLayer(
        "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", 
        {attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'}
    ).addTo(map);

    // Declare Variables
    // variable to hold pub locations
    var pubLocations = null;
    // variable to hold your location
    var youAreHere = null;

    // Find five closest pubs

    // Set Global Variable that will hold your location
    var myLocation = null;

    // Set Global Variable that will hold the marker that goes at our location when found
    var locationMarker = null;

    // Set 'Your Location' icon
    var redIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'markers/redIcon.png',
    });

    // Listen for a click event on the Map element
    map.on('click', locationFound);

    // Function that will run when the location of the user is found
    function locationFound(e){
      myLocation = e.latlng;
      closestPub();
      locationMarker = L.marker(e.latlng, {icon: redIcon});
      map.addLayer(locationMarker);
    };

    // Function that will run if the location of the user is not found
    function locationNotFound(e){
      alert(e.message);
    };

    // Function will find and load the five nearest pubs to a user location
    function closestPub(){
      // Set SQL Query that will return five closest pubs
      var sqlQueryClosest = "SELECT%20%22PubName%22,%20%22URL%22%20,%20%22geometry%22%20FROM%20%22UK_Pubs%22%20ORDER%20BY%20%22geometry%22%20<->%20ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("+myLocation.lng+","+myLocation.lat+"),%204326)%20LIMIT%205";

      // remove pubs if on map
      if(map.hasLayer(pubLocations)){
        map.removeLayer(pubLocations);
      };

      // remove locationMarker if on map
      if(map.hasLayer(locationMarker)){
        map.removeLayer(locationMarker);
      };

      // Get GeoJSON of five closest points to the user
    var beerIcon = new L.Icon({iconUrl: 'markers/beer.png'});

      $.getJSON("http://10.0.2.15:4000/sql?format=GeoJSON&q="+sqlQueryClosest, function(data) {
        pubLocations = L.geoJson(data,{
          pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {
              icon: beerIcon
            });
          },
          onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup('<p><b>' + feature.properties.PubName + '</b><br /><em>' + feature.properties.URL + '</em></p>');
          }
        }).addTo(map);
      });
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since we don't have your server to try it, can you tell a bit more about "cant get it to work"? You don't see anything? You don't see what you expected? No beer markers? Any errors in the debugger console? Do you run your app HTML from server or from your local file system? Adding excerpt from your GeoJSON data would also help.

Comment: This question is most likely to be closed. Please edit your original question and add necessary detail (see my first comment).